# NSThread callStackSymbols from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, background, nsthread

I have a background thread that polls UI thread every 200ms. If there is a hang for 2 seconds, I would like to get the call stack from UI thread at that point. When I call [NSThread callStackSymbols], it is executed on background thread since I check If the hang is more than 2 secs in background thread.

is there an easy way to get call stack on main thread from bg thread?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to do it "manually"**.
Well, if I understand you right one of the threads is doing some heavy lifting which takes too long time. For these cases I just hit the pause button in xcode to pause the debugger. Then it is easy to inspect the callstack and see which method is blocking from continuing.